# External HDD with Ubuntu boots in emergency mode

Tags: boot, hard-drive, laptop, hp, external-hdd

I recently installed Ubuntu on my 500GB external HDD with my Acer Aspire laptop from a live USB, the installation was successful (even installed grub on the external HDD) and I could boot from the external HDD with my Acer laptop. The problem is that that laptop only used as installation media and my goal was to use the external hard drive with Ubuntu installed on my main laptop which is an HP Envy, but when I turn on the laptop with the hard drive attached it boots normal at first even crashes see the logo of HP and Ubuntu while loading, but then emergency mode appears on the screen with the following:

Emergency mode boot:

[image: Emergency Mode Boot Image]

Results of `journalctl -xb | grep failed` :

[image: journalctl -xb | grep failed, image]

I don't know why Ubuntu starts on my Acer laptop and not on my HP laptop.

Comment: Different hardware/drivers causing problems -- did you run the suggested journalctl -xb to see more details?

Comment: @ubfan1 I already edited and put the image with the result of the journalctl -xb |  grep failed

Comment: Check the UUIDs of the system (sudo blkid) against the /etc/fstab, and the UUID used in the /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg (should be your root UUID).  That might fix many of the UUID errors. Is the video hardware the same on both machines (both either have or lack Nvidia etc.)? Might need to fix up the video drivers if they are for the wrong hardware.

Comment: @ubfan1 The Acer laptop I use as installation media has an Intel Pentium Silver CPU and graphics is the one integrated into the CPU and my main HP laptop has an AMD Ryzen 7 CPU with Radeon Vega Graphics